# Search in host or connect to database

Tags: php, database, image, directory

In my host I have over 1000 folders and I expect it to reach over 10000 folders.

All folders contents about 20 images.

I am currently use scandir to list all images in one folder and show only one image to user.

So, here is my question: for showing only one image in all of those images, should I store their name in the database and then load them by there id's, or use scandir and search entire folder?

By the way, my script is something like mangafox.com.

Comment: run a test ? it will be better than hearsay..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like if this is a **frequent activity** - you don't want to run `scandir` all the time. However, if the files **change frequently**, then you've added an additional problem of keeping the database synced with the filesystem.

It's really a trade off between simple, but sometimes slow (using `scandir` to build the file list) and complex, but faster (having to sync database and file system).

My suggestion would first be to build an array representing the results or `scandir` and cache that to the file system. That may be easier to keep in sync, and still provide faster performance (assuming it's for a single folder, not the entire structure).

Comment: I not changing any file or folder for that matter, and i am currently use array an cache system. i'm  just asking if database is faster or not.

Comment: @kamal And I'm saying a database is (probably) faster, but caching the output of `scandir` may be even faster, and simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really give any hard numbers, but the database will definitely make your site snappier. To scan directories for showing an image definitely won't scale as well as just quickly looking up a path to the image in the database and using that.

Also, you can use the database for other metadata regarding the images, for example comments or artist info that can be more difficult to add to an image using just the file system.